# How redirect to default language if not present in URL

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I´m using Mcamara Laravel/localization (https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) and I want to redirect to the default language if it's not present in the URL for SEO purposes.

If i go to www.mydomain.com, it should redirect to www.mydomain.com/en. If i go to www.mydomain.com/something, it should redirect to www.mydomain.com/en/something.

I want to redirect for avoid duplicated content with www.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com/en because is the same content and the same language. I don't want two URL´s with the same content. If your default language is 'en' you have the same content at www.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com/en/

How do I do this redirect? .htaccess or routes file?

I'm not able configure it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used the mcamara/laravel-localization package but I suppose you could create a simple route to detect when the language is not set in the URL and redirect to the default language.

Something like that:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return Redirect::to(Config::get('app.default_language'));  
});
```

But I suggest that you set a cookie so when the user switch to a different language you keep this language and if the user go back to the home page "/", you redirect to this language and not the default language.

**Update based on OP comment:**

If you want to redirect all the routes not containing a language you need to do something similar like that:

**app/filters.php:**

```
App::before(function($request){

  $params = explode('/', Request::path());

  if(count($params) >= 1){

    $language = $params[0];
    $languages = Config::get('app.languages'); //Available languages in your app ex.: array('en', 'fr', 'es')

    if(!in_array($language, $languages)){

      $default_language = Config::get('app.default_language');

      return Redirect::to($default_language.'/'.Request::path());
    }
  } 
});
```

*Note: I didn't try the code, for information purpose only.*

Comment: I want to redirect all the urls from my project without language in the URL string, not only '/'

Comment: Perfect!!! I was looking for this! I added a 301 to the redirect function: return Redirect::to($default_language.'/'.Request::path(), 301); https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633

Answer (score 3):

this answer was inspired by @FR6, his answer is old and does not cover all the problems, so I made another implementation.

I handled this issue with middleware and route grouping
tested in laravel 8.0

in your routes file **web.php** group all routes that require localization parameter

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'middleware' => 'setLocale'
], function() {
    // put your routes here
    Route::get('/welcome', function(){
       return "Hello";
    });
});
// add this so when you call route('...') you don't get the error "parameter 'locale' is not set"
// this is required because all laravel's default auth routes won't add the 'locale' parameter
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::defaults(['locale' => app('locale-for-client')]);

// redirect the home page route to a specific locale
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app('locale-for-client'));
});
```

create the middleware **SetLocale** with `php artisan make:middleware SetLocale`

in **app\Middleware\SetLocale.php** we will redirect to the correct route if no locale is found on the given url

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $url_lang = $request->segment(1);
        if($url_lang !== 'api') {
            if (!in_array($url_lang, config('app.locales'), true)) {
                return redirect(app('locale-for-client') . '/' . request()->path());
            }
            app()->setLocale($url_lang);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

register the middleware in **app\Http\Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'setLocale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
    ];
```

in **AppServiceProvider** we will define the fallback language.
in my implementation I used the client cookie and the browser defined locale to get the client locale.

```
    public function register()
    {
         $this->app->singleton('locale-for-client', function(){
            $seg = request()->segment(1);
            if(in_array($seg, config('app.locales'), true))
            {
                // if the current url already contains a locale return it
                return $seg;
            }
            if(!empty(request()->cookie('locale')))
            {
                // if the user's 'locale' cookie is set we want to use it
                $locale = request()->cookie('locale');
            }else{
                // most browsers now will send the user's preferred language with the request
                // so we just read it
                $locale = request()->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
                $locale = substr($locale, 0, 2);
            }
            if(in_array($locale, config('app.locales'), true))
            {
                return $locale;
            }
            // if the cookie or the browser's locale is invalid or unknown we fallback
            return config('app.fallback_locale');
        });
    }
```

next would want to set your locales in **config\app.php**

```
    'locales' => ['en', 'ar', 'fr'],
    'locales_text_display' => ['en' => 'English', 'ar' => 'العربية', 'fr' => 'Français'],
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

#### Optional

since you have setup the app locale, now you probably would want to let the client change their locale if they want.

1. create a controller with `php artisan make:controller AppLocaleController`
2. create the method update in the controller  **AppLocaleController**

```
public function update()
{
   if(in_array(request('locale'), config('app.locales'), true))
   {
      // using cookie('locale', request('locale')) will encrypt the cookie
      // manually set the cookie
      header("Set-Cookie:locale=".request('locale').";Max-Age=300000;path=/");
      return redirect(url('/'));
   }
   abort(400);
}
```

3. register the controller route

```
Route::post('/api/setLocale', [\App\Http\Controllers\AppLanguageController::class, 'update'])
    ->name('locale.update');
```

Comment: Whats mean app('locale-for-client')? and why you use this  if($url_lang !== 'api')? what is "api"? Thanks

Comment: for the first question what is app('locale-for-client') : this is just a global function I wrote, it's definition(registration) is on the 4th code block of the answer, this function will try to get or guess the locale(language) of the client. you can read the comments of the function for more details.

Comment: for the second question `if($url_lang !== 'api')`, here i'm checking if the first segment of the url has the word 'api' (like `mysite.com/api/users/1`), if it does we want to ignore the locale checking because this is an api request an not a normal browser request. for more informations check [laravel api](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)

Comment: Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::cookie does not exist.
this return me when I send form post to route /setLocale

Comment: And the request()->cookie('locale') always return null when is called in the singleton locale-for-client

Comment: @AntonioMorales Hello, sorry i didn't test the update method of the controller as it's optional, i have fixed it now, also don't forget to change the route url.to /api/setLocale